# Stack implementation with a linked list

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, stack

Could anyone provide any constructive criticism? I'm trying to get a jump on data structures before classes start.

One thing is that I should add a copy constructor and assignment operator. Changes made: got rid of `using namespace std`.

As the code allows users to specify a cap, if they wish, for their stack any ideas of how I could signal that that particular stack is full? Currently I'm outputting a message from within the method but I don't like it when method handle output. What about a method that returns whether the stack is full?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // TESTING

template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack()
        : head(nullptr), capacity(0), currSize(0), sized(false) 
    {}
    Stack(int cap)
        : head(nullptr), capacity(cap), currSize(0), sized(true) 
    {}
    ~Stack();

    void push(T val);
    void pop();
    bool isEmpty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const;
    T top() const;

private:
    template <typename T>
    struct StackNode
    {
        StackNode() 
            :data(0), next(nullptr) 
        {}
        StackNode(T val, StackNode *ptr = nullptr) 
            :data(val), next(ptr) 
        {}

        T data;
        StackNode *next;
    };

    StackNode<T> *head;
    int capacity;
    int currSize;
    const bool sized;
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    while (head != nullptr)
    {
        StackNode<T> *tmp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T val)
{
    if (sized == false || currSize != capacity)
    {
        head = new StackNode<T>(val, head);
        ++currSize;
    }
    else cout << "stack full" << endl; //delete
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        StackNode<T> *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete tmp;
        --currSize;
    }
}

template <typename T>
int Stack<T>::size() const
{
    return currSize;
}

template <typename T>
T Stack<T>::top() const
{
    if (head != nullptr)
    {
        return head->data;
    }
    else return NULL;
}



int main()
{
    Stack<char> myStack(3);

    cout << "is isEmpty: " << myStack.isEmpty() << endl;

    cout << "push: "; myStack.push('H'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    cout << "push: "; myStack.push('G'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    cout << "push: "; myStack.push('B'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    cout << "push: "; myStack.push('D'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    myStack.pop();
    cout << "push: "; myStack.push('D'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;


    cout << "Size: " << myStack.size() << endl;
    cout << "Destroyed" << endl;  myStack.~Stack();


    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause"); // TESTING
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you commented `using namespace std;` with `// TESTING` ?

Comment: So I don't get burned for using it lol

Comment: @user3392999 Oh, you'll get burned for that anyway :-) Don't worry though, it isn't personal.

Comment: haha! True! Once I'm happy with it I'll change it, then again it's only for my own personal use in the house as I learn, but then again it's not good to get in bad habits :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> using namespace std; // TESTING
> ```

Judging by your comment, I'm guessing you're aware about the problems of exposing namespace members in the global scope. But did you know that you can `using namespace` inside scopes other than the global? It is fine if in your unit tests you want to expose the `std` stuff to make the code less verbose, but do that in the shortest possible scope then, in this case, inside `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    // Make an exception since this is a unit test and expose
    // the whole Standard Library inside main(), so we don't have 
    // to std:: qualify everything.
    using namespace std;

    // same as before ...
}
```

---

> ```
>  cout << "Destroyed" << endl;  myStack.~Stack();
> ```

Very unusual for you to be calling the destructor for `myStack`. A destructor is called automatically when an object goes out of scope or is `delete`ed. There are very few cases where a programmer would manually call a destructor, those are not present here. If you just wan't to ensure the object is destroyed before the end of `main()`, to log some stuff, wrap its declaration inside a new scope. E.g.:

```
int main()
{
    {
        Stack<char> myStack(3);
        ...
    } // <== ~myStack() called here
}
```

This way you won't risk ending with a half destroyed object in your hands.

---

> ```
> template <typename T>
> T Stack<T>::top() const
> {
>     if (head != nullptr)
>     {
>         return head->data;
>     }
>     else return NULL;
>     //          ^^^^ problem here!
> }
> ```

That will not work for a `T` type that is not a pointer or integer. `NULL` can be assigned to integers because it is usually implemented as `#define` for `0`. That's one of the reasons why you should use [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) whenever possible (C++11). If you had used `nullptr`, your test with `T=char` would have failed and you would have noticed this problem.

The usual convention for a generic stack is to throw an exception if you try to access the top for an empty stack. Returning a "default" value is less generic and also makes it harder for the caller to detect errors. Returning a default also requires the type `T` to be default constructible, so don't do it.

Same goes for popping on an empty stack. Right now you are not generating any errors. You should consider throwing and exception. Deriving a `StackUnderflow` exception type from [`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) might be a good idea. Then you can extend the concept to a `StackOverflow` error when trying to push to the bounded stack. Granted that you can do with a simple `std::runtime_error`, but defining custom exception classes is a nice exercise if that's your point for writing this implementation.

---

> ```
> cout << "push: "; myStack.push('H'); cout << myStack.top() << endl;
> ```

Don't pack that many statements in a single line. People read shorter columns of text much faster. But not just that, mixing several statements together makes it a lot easier for a quick read to miss some important part of it. Put each statement in its own line.

```
cout << "push: "; 
myStack.push('H'); 
cout << myStack.top() << endl;
```

---

Not a huge thing, but usually this kind of data structures uses `std::size_t` for things like `size` and `capacity`. That's an unsigned integer, which makes sense since the stack size is not meant to be negative, however, there is some discussion about [avoiding unsigned integers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/laurionb/unsigned-considered-harmful), so that's up to you to decide if it is worth it.

---

Last thing is a bit of a big subject, which was introduced with C++11, called *move semantics*. Your code does some unnecessary copying of data on `push` and `StackNode`'s constructor, which might affect performance when `T` is something other that a native type or pointer. I'll leave you with a couple references you can read to further learn about this:

- [SO: What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics)
- [cppreference.com: Move constructors.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)

Comment: That's great thanks! One question - I used the destructor just go see if it did clear the stack, if I wanted a function to clear the stack should I just wrap the destructor in a method called clear() ?

Comment: @user3392999, Sure! Having a public `clear()` is a good idea. That allows you to implement the destructor by simply calling the clear function.

Answer (score 6):

You've quite correctly marked the `Stack full` printout with a `delete` comment, however you **must** give an indication that `push` failed. An easiest way is to make it return `bool`.

It is unclear why do you want to restrict stack capacity. The only reason of implementing stack via a linked list (as opposed to fixed-size array) is to have a virtually unlimited capacity.

`StackNode` default constructor is never used (and never shall be used), so I recommend to make sure it is never called. In any case it should initialize `data` as `data(T(0))`.

Comment: Won't the default constructor be called if I don't specify a value? Such as Stack<int> myStack ?

Comment: @user3392999, vnp meant the default constructor you've written for `StackNode`. Which is not useful because you only crate stack nodes with `new StackNode<T>(val, head);`. To prevent misuse of `StackNode`, you could either make the default constructor `private` or delete it altogether with `StackNode() = delete;` in the declaration.